# 2002 Ford Explorer won't start

Tags: ford, starting, troubleshooting, explorer

I've had it for about two years now, and didn't have this problem until recently. At one occasion after a long trip it wouldn't start after parking for a few minutes.. the next morning it fired right up. A few months went by with  no trouble until last weekend; I drove it to work all week and then on Saturday it fails to start and hasn't since. Turning the key over I have lights, radio, the starter spins , etc. I do have pressure from exhaust while trying to start as well. What do you think is the issue?

Comment: Can you hear the fuel pump turn on when you turn the key halfway and all the lights turn on?

Comment: No, I couldn't hear anything. from reading I've done it seems that might be the case.

Comment: Does the 2002 Ford Explorer have an IC in the key, such that it wouldn't start with a duplicated key? My car has the same problem. I figured that the proximity sensing was not too perfect especially on rainy days - and all I had to do was pull the key out and turn it over and reinsert the key and my car starts.

Answer (score 2):

Your fuel pump might be dead or not getting power. I would check that, it's the most likely, and also the fuel filter.

I would also check to see if you get spark at the spark plugs.

Comment: ok, based on what @BlessedGeek mentioned I went ahead and tried the keyless start. It fired up immediately, and afterwards the key is working. It is raining today. I'm still baffled on what exactly is the issue. I hate when problems "magically" go away.